# How to check if a Pull Request has merge conflicts in Github Actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I want to be able to determine if a Pull Request has **merge conflicts** in a GitHub Action's pipeline, and if they do run `echo this PR has merge conflicts`.

Comment: Please show your own effort and how that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [olivernybroe/action-conflict-finder](https://github.com/olivernybroe/action-conflict-finder), as example:

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  merge_conflict_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Find merge conflicts
    steps:
      # Checkout the source code so we have some files to look at.
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Run the actual merge conflict finder
      - name: Merge Conflict finder
        uses: olivernybroe/action-conflict-finder@v2.0
```

Comment: I don't think this does what the asker was looking for. This action seems to check whether you have accidentally committed files with unresolved merge conflicts to your repo, not whether there are any active PR merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CI job that fails when a PR includes merge conflicts:

```yaml
name: No unresolved conflicts
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  detect-unresolved-conflicts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: List files with merge conflict markers
        run: git --no-pager grep "<<<<<<<" ":(exclude).github/" || true
      - name: Fail or succeed job if any files with merge conflict markers have been checked in
        # Find lines containing "<<<<<<<", then count the number of lines.
        # 0 matching lines results in exit code 0, i.e. success.
        run: exit $(git grep "<<<<<<<" ":(exclude).github/" | wc --lines)
```

That's probably what you want, but I'm sure with some searching, you can convert it to only echo your error message rather than fail the build.